# I want css styles applied to child page body must not affect the parent page body?

Tags: php, html, css

I have php page in which another php page is embedded dynamically, both the pages have styles applied to its own body.

The final html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #f00;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Text in main body</div>


        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Email</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <style type="text/css">
                    body {
                        text-align: left;
                        background-color: #0f0;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>Text in child body</div>
            </body>
        </html>


    </body>
</html>
```

I want css styles applied to child body must not affect the parent body and vice versa.

I can edit main page only child page is not in my control and content of the child page is stored in a php variable.

Comment: Is the inner HTML inside an iframe? If not, the answer is simply that you can't put a HTML document inside another HTML document. Inspect your page using the browser tools; you will find that the inner <html> and <body> tags simply aren't there.

Comment: I can put iframe in main page to wrap the child page in it but don’t know how to put the html of child page in src of iframe. actually content of the child page is stored in a php variable.

Comment: If you have the source of the child page in PHP, then just change it to have a unique container. For example `<div id="childpage">` where you now have `<body>`, and `#childpage` in the CSS.

Comment: You can check out my answer, I think it will help you a lot :)

Comment: You can not have doctype, html and body multiple times in one HTML document, that is invalid to begin with. That is what you need to fix first of all.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your parent content in `div` with `class=wrap` and style in css the `.wrap`

**Note!** this is invalid html because you can not set HTML inside another HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style type="text/css">
            .wrap {
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #f00;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrap">Text in main body</div>


        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Email</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <style type="text/css">
                    body {
                        text-align: left;
                        background-color: #0f0;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>Text in child body</div>
            </body>
        </html>


    </body>
</html>
```